# undefined method `images_path' Error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I got an error and I dont know where it come from, this is my code **images_controller.rb**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'home2'
  #before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def crea
    @image = Image.new
  end

  def post
    @image = Image.new(params[:images])
  end
end
```

**post.html.erb**

```
<h2 align="center">Post your own creation right here !</h2>
<br>
<div align="center">
  <%= link_to 'Back', '/showcase', :class => "buttonShow" %>
</div>
<%= simple_form_for @image do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :description, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :nickname, :required => true %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Post !", :class => "buttonShow"  %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources "images", only: [:crea, :post]
  resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]
  get 'contacts/contact'

  get 'images/crea'
  get 'images/post'

  get 'auth/auth'

  root "auth#auth"
  #get 'contact' => 'contacts#contact'
  get 'showcase' => 'images#crea'
  get 'showcase/post' => 'images#post'
  #resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

I got always the same error who don't help me a lot :

```
undefined method `images_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ffe6c718578>:0x007ffe6c68ab38>
Did you mean?  image_alt
```

The line of code, where the error is supposed to be is according to the ruby error :

```
<%= simple_form_for @image do |f| %>
```

this is my models :

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
      attribute :title,      :validate => true
      attribute :description,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
      attribute :nickname, :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
```

end

---

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160927210003) do

      create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "email"
        t.string   "message"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
      end

      create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "title"
        t.string   "description"
        t.string   "nickname"
        t.string   "image_filename"
        t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
      end

    end
```

Thank's in advance,
See you soon,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `simple_forms` search the `images_path` with `POST` Method, that means the `create` action of your controller

But you have this

```
  resources "images", only: [:crea, :post]
  # Many other code
  get 'images/crea'
```

You can try changing the `resources` line to

```
  resources "images", only: [:crea, :create]
```

and in your controller

```
  class ImagesController < ApplicationController
    layout 'home2'
    #before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    def crea
      @image = Image.new
    end

    def create
      @image = Image.new(params[:images])
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your routes.rb file:

```
resources "images", only: [:crea, :post], path: 'images'
```

Comment: The error is still there, I really don't know why it doesnt work properly.

Comment: can you show your full error log from your terminal?

Comment: http://hpics.li/1bff42f  I got an other error when I open the rails console and create a Image object :http://hpics.li/1bff42f  I post on the first post the code of my model.

Comment: What happens when you change attribute :title, :validate => true to attribute :title, presence: true and also please add your schema.rb to your post.

Comment: With presence nothing change, I post the schema.rb up.

Comment: In your post action change do this @image = Image.new(params[:image]) ---- remove the 's' from images

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both, The solutions was concerning the name like Hugo describe it, thanks again.
Now, I have to pay more attention about the naming.